# I want to update a financial chart when I select a new stock from a popup menu

Tags: dynamic, curated-data, finance

I have the following code:

Read all the DOW jones financial instruments

`instruments = FinancialData["^DJI", "Members"]`

Then I create a dynamic variable called ticker

```
Dynamic[ticker]

ticker =.
```

And I create a popup menu with

```
{PopupMenu[Dynamic[ticker], instruments], Dynamic[ticker]}
```

So far it all works. I have my list of stock instruments in variable instruments and the popup menu comes up and when I pick a stock from it, the ticker (displayed to the right of the menu) updates to show the ticker I chose from the drop down list

My problem is that I would like to have a chart automatically updated once I pick a ticker. For now I have:

```
data = FinancialData[ticker, "OHLCV", {{2008, 7, 3}, {2008, 9, 30}}]
```

And I use

```
InteractiveTradingChart[data]
```

To display the chart

This works if I hit Shift enter on the last line. However, if I go to the popup menu and select a different stock (say INTC for Intel) the chart is not updated. I am new to Mathematica and I am sure that my problem is not understanding how Dynamic works.

What I don't understand

```
InteractiveTradingChart[data]
```

Comment: Indeed, welcome Henrick. You might have missed the question mark at the top right of your question entry box. This is a link that leads you to a short course in MarkDown, the layout system used here to prettify your text.

Comment: If you change your "data" definition to `data = Dynamic[
  FinancialData[ticker, "OHLCV", {{2008, 7, 3}, {2008, 9, 30}}]]` then the data will update automatically. If you change the chart to `InteractiveTradingChart[data[[1, All]]]` then it will recognize the new data when that line is evaluated. However, I can't figure out how to make the chart update automatically.

Answer (score 17):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish this is with [Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html).

```
Manipulate[
 InteractiveTradingChart[
  FinancialData[ticker, 
   "OHLCV", {{2008, 7, 3}, {2008, 9, 30}}]], {ticker, instruments}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm falling in love with Mathematica. Simple, effective.