# Manipulate InteractiveTradingChart or lazy Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, charts, finance, interactive

Back in 2012, it seems that something like `Manipulate[InteractiveTradingChart[ticker], {ticker, {"AMZN", "GOOGL"}}]` [worked fine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/i-want-to-update-a-financial-chart-when-i-select-a-new-stock-from-a-popup-menu/1712#1712). Mathematica 12.2 however is not able to handle this anymore and seems to get stuck in some kind of initialization loop.

It would be great if this functionality could be restored by Wolfram. In the meantime, I am curious whether there exists a workaround.

Is it for example possible to instruct `Manipulate` to trigger computation only when a parameter value changes and avoid precomputing results, i.e., is there a way to make `Manipulate` "lazy"?

Comment: For the last question, look at [TrackedSymbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html).

Comment: Thank you for the hint but could you be more explicit on how this could solve the problem with `InteractiveTradingChart`? For example, `Manipulate[InteractiveTradingChart[ticker], {ticker, {"AMZN", "GOOGL"}}, {u, {1, 2}}, TrackedSymbols :> {u}]` does not work, i.e., clicking on values for `u` does not result in a working plot.

Comment: It look like s the approach using `Manipulate` is broken in V12, but I have found that `TabView` works well. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Module[{amzn, googl},
  amzn = InteractiveTradingChart[{"AMZN", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}];
  googl = InteractiveTradingChart[{"GOOGL", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}];
  TabView[{"AMZN" -> amzn, "GOOGL" -> googl}]]
```

[image: tab_a]

[image: tab_g]

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: By the way, replacing `TabView` by `MenuView` works as well.

Comment: @MathGaudium. Indeed.